# Add trailing slash to url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a trailing slash to urls using PHP. It can't be done with mod_rewrite since I have something similar to this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

and I want to validate that the page exists before 301 redirect with trailing slash.

Right now I'm using this code after validation:

```
if(substr($_GET['page'], -1) !== '/')
  header('Location: http://example.com/'.$_GET['page'].'/'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],TRUE,301);
```

But is there any better approach?

Comment: I don't understand you can do it as a mod rewrite?

Comment: I don't want to add trailing slashes for pages that doesn't exist e.g. example.com/page/fokwaofkw becomes example.com/page/fokwaofkw/

Comment: And how do you check the existence of that requested resource?

Comment: Lets say the request is 
`/page/1`
which will really be
`/index.php?page=1`
, I need to validate so the page "1" exists in my database before redirecting with trailing slash

Comment: Usually you would do this using apache RewriteConditions. But if you insist on only adding slashes to urls for an insisting `page` you can only do this in code once you've validated the existence of the page.

Comment: What happens currently if the page doesn't exists in your db?

Comment: @user422039: In that case you already have the best solution.

Comment: @Gumbo: So there's nothing I need to change in that code? No need to encode anything before putting it into headers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the best solution for this. I would just use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of the already parsed `$_GET['page']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`:

```
if (substr($_GET['page'], -1) !== '/') {
    $parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
    $uri = 'http://example.com'.$parts[0].'/'.(isset($parts[1]) ? '?'.$parts[1] : '');
    header('Location: '.$uri, true, 301);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why not use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] directly without explode()? Shouldn't that produce the same result?

Comment: @Ibrahim AshShohail: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the originally requested URI path and query. With `explode` you split it at the `?` separator to put the missing `/` at the end of the URI path and re-append the query if it was already present in the originally requested URI.

Comment: My bad... I thought the REQUEST_URI would be "pages/1/", so that defeats the purpose in the first place. =) Thanks, Gumbo.

Comment: @Ibrahim AshShohail: Actually, mod_rewrite’s *REQUEST\_URI* is different from PHP’s *REQUEST\_URI*. That might cause some confusion.

Answer (score 52):

Simple way is that just remove the slash if available at the end of url and add it

```
$str = "http://yoursite.com/testpage"; 

OR 

$str = "http://yoursite.com/testpage/";


echo rtrim($str,"/").'/';
```

Comment: simply awesome piece

Comment: the simplest way to add / without any hassle

Comment: Does not work with:
$str = "http://yoursite.com/testpage?id=1"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my universal solution, hope it helps for somebody:

```
 $site_adress = (((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$whole_url = $site_adress . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


$pos = strpos($whole_url, "?");
$changed_url = FALSE;
if($pos !== FALSE && $whole_url[$pos - 1] != "/") {
    $whole_url = substr_replace($whole_url, "/", $pos, 0);
    $changed_url = TRUE;
} else if($pos == FALSE && substr($whole_url, -1) != '/') {
    $whole_url = $whole_url . "/";
    $changed_url = TRUE;
}
if($changed_url) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: " . $whole_url);
    exit();
}
```